# Nginx multiple domains shared resources

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have the following folders:

```
/web/domain1/  
/web/domain2/  
/web/shared/
```

I want domain1 and domain2 to share static files from `/web/shared/` but I am having trouble creating the mapping in nginx.

```
domain1: /assets/  mapped to /web/shared/  
domain2: /admin/assets/ mapped to /web/shared/
```

```
server{
    server_name domain1;
    root /web/domain1/;

    location / {
        rewrite /assets/(.*) /web/shared/$1;
    }        
}
```

This gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
location /assets/(.*) {
    alias /web/shared/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `location` for URIs that begin with `/assets/` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details). Use the `alias` directive, as the `root` directive cannot be used in this case (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details).

For example:

```
location /assets/ {
    alias /web/shared/;
}
```

Comment: I am getting 403 Forbidden error.  I checked the permissions and they look ok.  Also, nginx seems to add a trailing slash to the url.

Comment: Yes.  "...directory index of /web/shared/ is forbidden ..."

Comment: This seems to work: `location /assets/(.*) { alias /web/shared/$1; }`

Comment: If you'd like to update the answer, I can go ahead and accept it.  Thks

Comment: If you have found a solution that works for you, you can [post it as an answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).